# How do antibiotics create drug-resistant strains

Tags: pharmacology, pathology

I've heard for years that low-level use of antibiotics causes the spread of drug-resistant strains of bacteria, but the explanations always fall short.  I understand mutations and natural selection, and that a bacterium can randomly mutate into one that is more resistant to the antibiotic than the wild-type.  I understand that the antibiotics kill off the less resistant strains and leave the more resistant ones, but those more resistant strains would be there even without the antibiotic use, right?

Do the more resistant bacteria compete somehow with the less resistant ones and the antibiotics kill off the competition?

(Edited: previously used the terms "strong" and "weak" which apparently have unintended connotations, and was unclear about the role of mutation).

Comment: The last part of your question is confusing. Can you reword your question and talk about mutants and wild-type instead of "strong" and "weak"? Those are value-laden words, and may not even apply to the populations you're talking about.

Comment: Resistance to an antibiotic doesn't make it "strong"; it makes it resistant to an antibiotic. If it happens to take hold in a wound, it will flourish no better than a wild-type bacteria, but it will survive exposure to the antibiotic, that's all.

Comment: Resistant strains might have been there but they would not have been in a position to outcompete the nonresistants without selection, for the reasons I gave in my answer. If you properly treat bacterial infections long enough and at a high enough dose with a combination of drugs, and have a patient with a functioning immune system, then the adaptive immune response should be able to clear the infection. When we didn't allow that to happen, or we gave antibiotics for viruses, we selected for the resistant mutants, and the adaptive response wasn't able to target and clear them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "stronger" or "weaker" strain until the bacteria are treated with antibiotics.

It is true that potentially antibiotic-resistant mutants will still occur whether or not treated with antibiotics.

However, the mutants would not be "stronger" without the antibiotic use, so there is no selective pressure for them to survive to any greater degree than the wild-type. Without the antibiotic, something else will kill that mutant bacteria, meaning that the mutation ultimately did not make it any stronger.

Answer (score 1):

All things being equal, in an environment without the selective pressure of the antibiotic, then the non-resistant wild-type will have a growth advantage.

**EDIT**

> The events of random mutation and the attendant natural selection in the presence of a given antibiotic provide ample opportunity for the advent of the resistance phenotype. It is interesting to note that the survival cost to the microorganism in the evolution of drug resistance is high as it is highly dependent on the environment in which it happens to exist momentarily. One could envision that in the case of a plasmid-borne resistance factor, the organism must synthesise the additional genetic material and the protein that it encodes. However, this energy cost factor may be affected by the nutritional limits of the environment in which the organism finds itself. Furthermore, alterations of chromosomal genes encoding the targets for antibacterials may present the opportunity for the selection of resistance to antibiotics. However, such modifications may jeopardise the normal function of the gene products and make the organism that carries them less fit in the wild, or diminish or lose the capacity to survive in the absence of the antibiotic. Numerous studies indicate that genetic adaptation by secondary mutations elsewhere in the genome and natural selection reduces this ‘cost’ to the organism in several generations of growth, such that the cost is either reduced or eliminated entirely. Indeed, recent studies suggest that a progression of bacterial resistance to given noxious agents involves a sequence mechanism that renders the organism increasingly resistant to the agent, but nevertheless at a cost to its survival fitness

-Martins, A., Spengler, G., Molnár, J. and Amaral, L. 2014. Bacterial Antibiotic Resistance. eLS.

In order to truly grant resistance to an antibiotic, the bacterium needs to be expressing the enzyme the confers resistance constitutively so that it can react to the antibiotic when the cell comes in contact with the antibiotic. If the bacterium has to wait until it encounters the antibiotic to start expressing the resistance gene, then the bacterium will likely be killed before it has a chance to produce the protein that will protect it. This is especially true for antibiotics that target the bacterial ribosomes to prevent protein synthesis.

The result is that the bacterium has to use energy to produce the enzyme. It also has to maintain that gene either on a plasmid or incorporated in a very small genome. That again means the resistant cell needs more energy for replication, and likely a bit more time to divide. That may seem trivial, but if the nonresistants can divide every 20 minutes while it might take the resistants 25 or 30 minutes, the resistant bacteria will be out competed by the nonresistant bacteria, for the simple fact that the nonresistants are using less energy to survive and replicate and they are doing it faster, so the will have more descendants.

Another thing that you need to realize is that a lot of times the use of antibiotics only holds a bacterial infection in check until our adaptive immune system can be raised and respond to the infection. So not completing a course of antibiotics means that during the period of time that the antibiotic was used the resistant bacteria had a growth advantage over the nonresistant bacteria.

If you stop taking the antibiotic before the immune system can clear the infection completely, then both types of bacteria will begin to divide again, and there will be more of the resistant bacteria than there will be nonresistant, so they will contribute more descendants to the reemerging infection.

Another problem is that the more resistant bacteria there are the more of a chance there is that they can pass on that resistance gene to bacteria that didn't have it before. Now when you go back on the antibiotic, less and less of the bacteria in the infection will be affected, and you will get uncontrolled growth of the infection. There is a point where your immune system either is overwhelmed and cannot respond, the toxicity level from endo and exo toxins produced by the bacteria makes you very sick, or your immune response responds too strongly and does significant damage to your own tissue trying to fight off the bacteria.

Comment: "All things being equal, in an environment without the selective pressure of the antibiotic, then the non-resistant wild-type will have a growth advantage." Do you have a source for this? CA (community associated)-MRSA has mostly replaced HA (hospital associated)-MSRA because their *doubling time is much less*, giving them a competitive advantage over even "feral" SA unrelated to their methicillin resistance.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Your example is of an already resistant, already highly virulent strain of bacteria, and that is not what I am describing. I am describing how you go from a situation where the majority of the organisms are non-resistant and then through the incorrect use of antibiotics, you give rise to strains that have resistance.

Comment: Must it be *incorrect use*? What about *correct use*? All I'm asking for is a source to back up your claims. If you don't have one (or more), it's just opinion.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I also looked at several papers on CA-MRSA, and non them mentioned anything about a growth rate advantage due to replication speed. They have different virulence factors, and are more adept at causing infections in otherwise health people, and the prevalence of these infections has increased dramatically in comparison to HA, but non mentioned the rate at which they replicate.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Incorrect usage was the bases of the OPs question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Edit to show source that supports my experimental observations.

Comment: How does low-level translate to incorrect usage? (I assumed lower dose, not incorrect.) Note the great difference in the *possibilities* they state and the certainties with which you frame your answer. I can easily accept the paper's hypotheses. You state it as if it's a known fact. The fact that you restricted antibiotic use to incorrect use shows a certain frame of reference which is restrictive, not open. "... my experimental observations." Are you doing microbiological research?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Yes.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I translated low-level use to be at amounts below minimum inhibitory concentration or incomplete treatment, and much of the first part of my answer, while factually accurate, was geared more towards correcting the OP's misconception that nonresistant = weaker. The advantage that resistants enjoy goes away when there is no selective pressure, because better breeders win out. Once established, as with MRSA and the other superbugs, they will be the predominant strain, because they have survived countless generations of selection that WTs did not. Their competition was wiped out.

Comment: I see a lot of explanation of how low-level use of antibiotics makes the ratio of resistant to non-resistant climb, but I don't see anything that would explain the absolute population of resistant going up or, more to the point, more people being infected with the resistant strain, because of the antibiotic use.

Comment: @user170733 Vertical Gene transfer. If, in a selective environment, the resistant strain is able to pass on its genes through replication, the larger the population gets in relation to non-resistants. Horizontal Gene Transfer. Resistant Bacteria, either the same species or entirely different ones are able to transfer the resistance gene, either by Transformation, Transduction, or Conjugation. Without antibiotics, there is no selective pressure, so the energy cost outweighs the benefit of resistance. With selection, the resistance gene(s) can be maintained...

Comment: @user170733 So now, because of decades of antibiotic use that was insufficient to kill off resistant strains, either below MIC, incomplete treatment, or from immunocompromised people that did not have an immune cyst that could fight the resistant bacteria, we have more resistant strains, and the rest is down to probability. More resistant strains = a higher probability that that is what will infect you.

Comment: @user170733 The issue isn't so much that antibiotics were used, it is that they were not used in high enough doses, for long enough periods of time and were often used as mono-therapies, instead of combination therapies that attack the bacteria multiple ways, making it less likely, at least initially, that you will have any bacterium will be resistant to all of the drugs, which is what we see now, because one drug didn't kill them, so the survivors are mostly killed by the second, but there are some that survive because they develop resistance to the second drug as well, and on and on.

Comment: @AMR - "I also looked at several papers on CA-MRSA, and non them mentioned anything about a growth rate advantage due to replication speed." Seriously? It's [*everywhere*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC139674/) (it's a very hot topic.) Makes it difficult to comprehend your statements...

Comment: @anongoodnurse The paper only has a comparison between CA and HA. I tried to find the reference, but it was from a book (peer-review?) that I wasn't able to track down. You are giving one example, and when it comes to bacteria, I have learned never say never, but that doesn't change the fact that sub minimum inhibitory concentrations that reduce the competition for resistant strains is one of the driving forces in their emergence and prevalence. I provided you with a peer-reviewed link that backs that up, which you are not satisfied with. You got your downvote, let it go at that.

Comment: @anongoodnurse If that isn't enough, then please feel free to raise an edit to suggest the changes you would like to see, or submit your own answer to the question.